# Entity Framework Core RowVersion column not updating using PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I've set a RowVersion column for my entity but it seems that it isn't storing anything on creates or updates.

it have this configuration in the DbContext `OnModelCreating`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .Property(a => a.RowVersion)
    .IsConcurrencyToken()
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

However, the RowVersion column is always NULL, even after an entity update / create.

By the way, I'm using PostgreSQL with the Npgsql Library (NuGet).
In the docs, it says that [PostgreSQL doesn't support computed values on add or update](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html#computed-columns-on-add-or-update)

Is it the reason why it doesn't work?

If so, why could we circumvent this limitation?

Also, I've tested with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property<byte[]>("RowVersion")
    .HasColumnName(ShadowPropertiesDb.RowVersion)
    .IsRowVersion();
```

It results in the same problem.

Comment: I can't test on PostgreSQL, but what's the type of `RowVersion` property? And if it's `byte[]`, did you try `.IsRowVersion()` instead of `.IsConcurrencyToken().ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` ?

Comment: Yes, it's a byte[]. Check the updated question. I've tried it. No with no luck :(

Comment: For timestamp/rowversion to work as intended the db engine should support it. What I read, PostgreSQL doesn't support auto-updating columns so you'll have to find a way to update concurrency tokens yourself. maybe [this](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc.html) gives a clue.

Comment: Afaik postgre uses different type for rowversion instead of byte[]

Comment: http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc.html#optimistic-concurrency-and-concurrency-tokens You cannot do that with postgreSQL when using EF, but you can use modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ForNpgsqlUseXminAsConcurrencyToken(); I use own counter column which I update to every entity in generic context method when savechanges is called.

Answer (score 8):

In PostgreSQL RowVersion is predefined as a column named "xmin".

Example property (only for Npgsql):

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[Column("xmin",TypeName = "xid")]
public long RowVersion { get; set; }
```

If you want the property to be byte[] type:

Step 1: Change property type to byte[]

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[Column("xmin",TypeName = "xid")]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Step 2: Add converter in "OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)"

```
var converter = new ValueConverter<byte[], long>(
     v => BitConverter.ToInt64(v, 0), 
     v => BitConverter.GetBytes(v));

builder.Entity<Author>()
   .Property(_ => _.RowVersion)
   .HasConversion(converter);
```

================ For many database type =================

Property:

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

In "OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)":

```
if (Database.IsNpgsql())
{
    var converter = new ValueConverter<byte[], long>(
        v => BitConverter.ToInt64(v, 0),
        v => BitConverter.GetBytes(v));

    builder.Entity<Author>()
            .Property(_ => _.RowVersion)
            .HasColumnName("xmin")
            .HasColumnType("xid")
            .HasConversion(converter);
}
```

Comment: This successfully prevents multi user conflicts, but does not let me add new objects: `PostgresException: 42703: column "xmin" of relation "Author" does not exist`

Comment: builder.Entity<Author>()
            .Property(_ => _.RowVersion)
            .HasColumnName("xmin")
            .HasColumnType("xid")
            .HasConversion(converter)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
            .IsConcurrencyToken();